# Normal Map - strange pixels on UV edges

Tags: normals, texture-baking, baking, normal-map

Im trying to bake a normal map and it looks more less correct in general. Except of strange colorful pixels that I get on UVs edges. Not everywhere, but in some places.

[image]

I dont really understand what is the source of this pixels. Im using Cage for baking and base mesh as Low Poly (the one that was copied and subdivided for sculting). So geometry of HP and LP meshes quite same.

Here is the Cage:

[image]

On the model the issue looks like this.

[image]

Here is the config for baking that I have and the model itself.

[image]

[image]

Blender file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/6d43fvazsu954i6/drakkar_normal_bake.blend/file

In tutorials that I watch this issue simply doesnt exist.

Did anyone face the same problem or has any guess about the reason behind it?

Thank you!

**Update 1**

The issue appears to be bad HP geometry that is hard to follow with LP object that leads to LP geometry protruding beyond the edge of the HP.

Like here:

[image]
[image]

Which looks quite obvious.

I got misled by "pixelation" of it, but when I actually aligned UVs along grid I got lines instead of pixels.

Comment: Hello, have you shade smoothed the object before baking? Maybe share your file so that we can try a bake?

Comment: @moonboots Hi, thanks for the reply. I tried Auto Smooth and Smooth. Here is the blender file https://www.mediafire.com/file/6d43fvazsu954i6/drakkar_normal_bake.blend/file 
The HP model is 7 million verts, so maybe a bit slow, depends on pc.

Comment: Yes it will be too heavy for my computer  ;)

Comment: Took a look at file.  The colors on your normal map are not necessarily a problem: these are places of *rapidly changing normals*, where one ray/sample will get a very different value than an adjacent one.  However, you should remove sharp edges on your LP+cage and disable autosmooth to prevent discontinuities.  After that, judge the normal map by the mapped object, not by the image.

Comment: Hi @Nathan
Thanks for taking a look! I think the reason of this issue is that my HP has very bad edges, they are quite random and its hard to follow the shape with less geometry. This issues happen only in place where my LP going out of HP shape. And as you said because I have very different normals, it baked some parts of hortizontal faces as vertical, because they were about vertical part of HP. 
And it looks pixilated on normal because of UVs being not strictly oriented along the grid. If you use "follow active quad" stuff ,this pixel's become lines.

Comment: @Nathan
However I tried to apply bevel modifier before baking and got same issue. I believe that I just have to shape HP better, so I can easier follow its shape when I retopoly it with less geometry and not have LP geometry protruding beyond the edge of the HP geometry.